# Getting exception and high fees in a simple UniV2 swap

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Function approve() works perfectly, while ethToTokens() gives an unreal high fee and also causes an exception.

I cannot understand how to find the exception causing the issue in ethToTokens()

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance :)

(Attached code only includes necessary parts)

```
IUniswapV2Router02 usi =
    IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);

function approve(ERC20 _token) external restricted {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(_token);
    require(
        token.approve(
            address(usi),
            0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        ),
        "approve failed."
    );
}

function ethToTokens(uint256 amountOutMin, address payable _token)
    external
    restricted
{
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = usi.WETH();
    path[1] = _token;
    usi.swapETHForExactTokens(
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: This is the only error details I get in Remix. "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted"

Comment: Has the user sent the tokens to the contract? You have to use approve and transferFrom like it explained here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/50251.